# Help with relative positioning

Tags: css, cross-browser

I'm trying to have the customer's shopping cart display when they mouse over My Cart.  I'd like to use CSS for this effect but I'm running into an issue where `.cart` is causing `.my-cart` to stretch to the size of `.cart`...

**update**

Now that's fixed, but the `.my-cart:hover` effect does not apply when I mouseout of `.my-cart` and into `.cart`... since `.cart` is inside of `.my-cart` it shouldn't be doing that

```
.tab {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.my-cart .cart {
    position: relative;
    visibility: none;
    top: 0;
    right: 136px;
    z-index: 2;

    width: 450px;
    padding: 8px;
}
.my-cart:hover .cart {
        visibility: normal;
}

        <ul class='clearfix'>
            <li class='tab my-account'><div>My Account</div></li>
            <li class='tab my-cart'><div>My Cart (0 items)</div>
                        <div class='cart'>asdfasdfasdf</div>
                </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Try setting .my-cart to position:relative and .cart to position:absolute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put `absolute` positioned elements in `relative` positioned ones, so that it's positioned relative to its parent (or the first parent that has a position:relative). Top/bottom and right/left can only be used in the position:absolute elements.